# How can I use TexReg (1.36.4) for a "relogit" model estimated using Zelig (v. 5.0-13)?

Tags: r, latex, texreg

I know that `Zelig` is a wrapper... But still, it provides nice simulation capabilities (which I wouldn't be able to do on my own).

Lets say I have this data,

```
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(5)         
x2 = rnorm(5)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))
y = rbinom(5,1,pr)

df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
```

Now, we estimate the model,

```
library(Zelig)    
relogit <- zelig(y ~ x1 + x2, model = "relogit", data = df)
```

And now, we (try to) make the table

```
library(texreg)
texreg(relogit)
```

... only to get this error.

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, stable):
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for 
signature ‘"Zelig-relogit"’
```

I am aware of the `$getvcov()` and `$getcoef()` functions. But I wonder how I could make a straightforward table using `texreg`. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`texreg` uses a generic function called `extract` to pull the relevant data from a model object and then processes the resulting `texreg` object to create a regression table. In order to extend the range of models `texreg` is applicable to, you can write your own methods for the `extract` function.

`Zelig-relogit` objects apparently store a `glm` object with the relevant data somewhere inside the object and attach a different class name to it. So it should be relatively straightforward to create a copy of this sub-object, fix its class name, and apply the existing `extract.glm` method to this object to extract the data. More specifically:

```
# extension for Zelig-relogit objects (Zelig package >= 5.0)
extract.Zeligrelogit <- function(model, include.aic = TRUE, include.bic = TRUE, 
    include.loglik = TRUE, include.deviance = TRUE, include.nobs = TRUE, ...) {
  g <- model$zelig.out$z.out[[1]]
  class(g) <- "glm"
  e <- extract(g, include.aic = include.aic, include.bic = include.bic, 
      include.loglik = include.loglik, include.deviance = include.deviance, 
      include.nobs = include.nobs, ...)
  return(e)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("Zelig-relogit", "Zelig"), 
    definition = extract.Zeligrelogit)
```

This code creates a `Zelig-relogit` method for the `extract` function. You can use it by typing something like `screenreg(relogit)`, where `relogit` is the name of your `Zelig-relogit` object. The result should look like this:

```
==================================
                Model 1           
----------------------------------
(Intercept)     -9446502571.59 ***
                     (62615.78)   
x1              19409089045.70 ***
                    (141084.20)   
x2                856836055.47 ***
                     (98175.65)   
----------------------------------
AIC                       6.00    
BIC                       4.83    
Log Likelihood           -0.00    
Deviance                  0.00    
Num. obs.                 5       
==================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

More generally, if you want to make any `Zelig` model work with `texreg`, you should look at `model$zelig.out$z.out[[1]]` to find the relevant information. I will include the `Zelig-relogit` `extract` method in the next `texreg` release.